# Is using a test entity manager a legitamate testing practice?

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, testing

I'm told by Devs senior to me, but less experienced with Hibernate, that wiring an entity manager into your Unit Test suite to be used to set up your database is not a legitimate practice.  ...but I'm sceptical because I've already worked at several places where this was done. Note that Hibernate is already being used to set up the test H2 db.

I've been asked to "prove" that it is legitimate. How can I do this?  Is this a community standard way of doing it? Does anyone know of a good link I can use?  Although I am myself on the hunt for such, I smell a bit of religion here so I'm probably going to need a really killer one or perhaps a large number of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your senior devs are referring to is, proper, white-box testing.

When you are doing Unit testing, you want to test *only* the given unit. This becomes more complicated when you start involving things like a database, or some external web service. The point remains, however: you still only want to test the one piece of code the Unit test is intended for; not some database.

Whether or not you have confidence in hibernate, or your database, is irrelevant. You need to "mock" the database transaction, the EntityManager, etc. I would look into something along the lines of EasyMock. Really its all up to you what you want to use. If you google for "mock junit" you will likely come up with a list of results where you can choose the framework that is right for you. The right framework for you, is a little beyond the scope of this discussion though.

Once you find what you want to use, the idea is that inside of your Unit test, instead of getting a real EntityManager, you have a mock object which you have mocked in such a way that:

> the documentation says that A will happen if I invoke method C, so I told the mock framework about it so it can fake it for me, so I don't have to rely on things outside of my Unit test

The reason why you want to mock an object like that, is because you can't rely on any other code that is not within that one Unit to work properly. Despite what you expect, and despite what the documentation says you should expect, if the code is written poorly, or in your case, if the database fails for some reason, then the unit test will fail. You can see how this might be a problem, because your function may execute flawlessly, but it fails because the database failed. This is not how unit testing is supposed to work - that's why its called unit testing...to test only a single unit at a time.

ALWAYS mock complicated Objects or functionality. Leaving things like String#equals(java.lang.Object) is OK. With doing this, you want to find a good middle ground. If you mock too much of your Unit test, then you lose confidence in the Unit test because your unit test is not actually invoking any actual code of yours. If you don't mock enough, then you are not doing unit testing properly, and your unit test is relying on things that have nothing to do with your code (i.e. database failure, third-party code written poorly, etc).

Your senior devs are correct. If you are using the real EntityManager in your Unit tests, then you are not actually doing unit testing at all.

Comment: In a perfect world this might be OK.  In the real world, I've worked on teams wherein other teams shared the same database and were prone to changing it without notification. This meant that constantly checking the consistency of the expected database structure in the actual Dev database was important. We WANT an error to happen somewhere under such conditions. In any case we ARE using a Hypersonic database. This is what doesn't make sense. Why bother trusting Hybernate in Prod and to create a test database to test against and yet not permit an entity manager to be used to set up tests?

Comment: PS, we do use EasyMock to test everything except DAOs in the manner described.

Comment: PSS. ...er somethin like that. ;-) We also used it as an opportunity to review the SQL Hibernate was using.

Comment: Well I think what you are getting at is still a little too complex. If you want to test the state of the database, that should be in its own separate unit test; make an assert that an error is thrown for this or that the commit succeeds for that. As far as the DAO calls itself (i.e. the function that makes the call) you should be mocking the database connection for that unit test. What you want to test for that unit is your logic for handling parameters to the function you are testing and that you are handling return values from functions that are called further down; the database is separate

Comment: What would be awesome is a component level integration test suite. That way you could separate tests like these from actual unit tests. Is there something like that out there?  I just tried to get a colleague to mock my DAOs he was using in his tests because his tests were breaking when I made changes. He declined and I'm the low man on the totem pole around here so I've little leverage.  I can evangelize but if other team members decline to comply...

Comment: Well if his tests are breaking because his tests have too many dependencies that have nothing to do with his test itself, then you can hardly be blamed for that. Its his own fault if he doesn't want to mock your DAOs. Specific to your question, I don't know what you mean. Unit tests are all the same; just testing a single unit. Personally, I've come to like using EasyMock and PowerMock in conjunction with each other to accomplish this. EasyMock can't do it that well by itself, but PowerMock integrates with EasyMock and fills in the gaps nicely.

Comment: No, it IS my fault if the local culture says it is. The trick is changing the culture.  I have to convince the entire team it's bad because they all do it, I'm sure.

Comment: In my experience, development is all about getting it done now, which many not necessarily mean right. Writing good JUnit tests, and full documentation, or rewriting faulty code rather than putting 'band-aids' on it making it worse, is always the right thing to do. Moreover, it will save time in the long run to spend 10 hours doing it right, rather than 4 hours doing it wrong and quick, then another 40+ hours over the next 2 years maintaining it. The problem is that managers only see the initial 4 hours and will never approve the time to do it right...what are you gonna do I guess? lol

Comment: then on top of that, you will end up having bad developers on any team you end up on. That's why most developers don't know how to write unit tests, or have never written a line of documentation in their life, or will post a comment on a message board before googling for an answer that they can get faster that way. Not everyone can be a genius, some people will do it wrong most of their career. That's why most software development is bug fixing rather than greenfield projects

Comment: OK so what I think is at issue is that they don't know that integration testing is done using a different maven goal and plugin other than test / Surefire. Specifically that would be the FailSafe plugin with the integration-test goal. It's not that I'm against integration tests, I just want them in the right place and you should know that what you're not doing is a unit test. IMHO not every unit test needs to be written anyway.