# JUnit concurrent access to synchronizedSet

Tags: java, junit, concurrency, synchronized

I have a problem with running JUnit tests on my server. When I run the test on my machine, there is no problem at all. When I run it on the server, there is a failure on all my server "sometimes". It means tests pass sometimes in 60% of attempts and 40% fail.

I am using Mockito. My test starts with mocking some replies using `MessageListener` and map every request to a response and under the hood I am using `Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>())` which is thread-safe.(Every modification on my synchronizedSet happens in a `synchronized(mySynchronizedSet){....}`) Then, I am using `RestAssurd` to get the response of a particular REST endpoint and assert some values.

When a test fails and I look on the Stacktrace, I see that one of my mappings (always on the same object) didn't work and there is no map between this specific request and response in my collection and naturally, I get `null` on requesting this endpoint.

I am using Jenkins to automate the compilation and running the test and I get the stack trace on fail or my Printlns otherwise, there are no debug facilities available.

It sounds like a concurrency problem to me. I mean it seems my collection does not have time to get ready before `RestAssurd` request for an endpoint. I've tested locks, sleep, and another simple java concurrency  solutions but they don't help and the probabilistic character of this problem has led me to a dead end.

Every thought will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by what you said, it seems you have a misunderstanding of how things work in 3 specific cases.

## **First**

and most obvious, and I apologize for even mentioning this, but the reason that I do at all is because I'm gathering that you're still learning (I apologize further if you're not still learning! and at the same rate, you might not have even implied it with the way I read it, so sorry if I misread): you aren't compiling with Jenkins, you're compiling with whatever JDK flavor you have on your machine (be it Oracle, Apple, GCJ, etc). Jenkins is an automation tool that helps facilitate your tedious jobs you expect to run regularly. I only mention this because I know college students nowadays use IDE's in there opening classes and can't distinguish between the compiler, the runtime, and the IDE.

## Secondly

by using a threadsafe library, it doesn't automatically make everything you do inherently threadsafe. Consider the following example:

```
  final Map<Object, Object> foo = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap <>());
  final String bar = "bar";
  foo.put(bar, new Object());
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
          foo.remove(bar);
      }
  }).start();
  new Thread(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
          if(foo.containsKey(bar)){
              foo.get(bar).toString();
          }
      }
  }).start();
```

There is no guarantee that the second thread's call to `#get(Object)` will happen before or after the first thread's call to `#remove(Object)`. Consider that

1. the second thread could call `#containsKey(Object)`
2. then the first thread obtains CPU time and calls `#remove(Object)`
3. then the second thread now has CPU time and calls `#get(Object)`

at this point, the returned value from `get(Object)` will be null, and the call to `#toString()` will result in a NullPointerDereference. You say you're using Set, so this example using a Map is mainly to prove a point: just because you're using a threadsafe collection, doesn't automatically make everything you do threadsafe. I imagine there are things you are doing with your set that match this sort of behavior, but without code snippets, I can only speculate.

## And Lastly

You should be careful with how you write JUnits. A proper JUnit test is what's called a "whitebox" test. In otherwords, you know everything that is happening in the test, and you are explicitly testing everything that is happening in only the unit under test. The unit under test is just the method you are calling - **not** the methods that are called by your method, only the method itself. What that means, is that you need a good mocking framework, and mock out any subsequent method calls that your unit under test may invoke. Some good frameworks are JMockit, Mockito+PowerMock, etc.

The importance of this is that your test is supposed to test your isolated code. If you're allowing network access, disk access, etc, then your test may fail and it may have nothing to do with code you wrote, and it invalidates the test entirely. In your case, you hint at network access, so imagine that there is some throughput issue with your switches/router/etc, or that your NIC buffer gets full and can't process fast enough for what your program is trying to do. Sure, the failure is not good, and should be fixed, but that should be tested in "blackbox" testing. Your tests should be written so that you eliminate these sort of issues from being present and only test your code in the particular method for the unit under test, and nothing else.

Edit: I actually posted an answer to a separate discussion about whitebox testing that might be relevant: [Is using a test entity manager a legitamate testing practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329977/is-using-a-test-entity-manager-a-legitamate-testing-practice/26330436#26330436)

Comment: Nice answer, but two things: A) I wouldnt even mention Powermock towards a newbie and B) keep in mind that yes, JUnit is mainly meant for "unit tests"; but that term is very wide, and many people are using Junit for whatever tests, and that is just fine. JUnit is just a tool, and it works for true unit tests, but also for any other kind of test.

Comment: Fair points. As far as the PowerMock though, Im not sure theres a way around that. Whitebox testing you kind of have to know about all that stuff to even begin to do it properly and I'll say Mockito+PowerMock are much more tame than JMockit so I'd actually prefer to mention that one. Mockito+PowerMock read like English, whereas JMockit is really difficult to read and understand how it works, in my opinion anyway. I found that devs who dont dive into the details of properly mocking end up with wrong unit tests, and the tests end up not doing what they think it's doing. He may not have a choice

Comment: Thing is: one needs Powermock when the design is using **static** in the wrong place; or **new** without proper thinking. In other words: when writing new code, the need to Powermock directly translates to "bad design" in my eyes. After watching these videos https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 ... I figured that I absolutely do not need Powermock (and the various small and big issues that often come with it) at all; and since many months I have not regretted that I completely stopped using it.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I am a newbie in the Java world and have a long way to learn. 1) It was a mistake in describing Jenkins. 2) I understand your second explanation and I should have explained and I am both using Mockito and synchronized my SynchronizedSet whenever I want to modify it. I am actually trying to figure out why everything goes well on the machine I am developing but not on my test server. 3) Nice point

Comment: Well as I mentioned it could be one of the last two points I made. Consider that your development machine and test server have different hardware configurations and likely very different things that are taking CPU time. Synchronization problems are characteristically difficult to debug because they might happen and they might not. If your development machine is slower, for instance, maybe something that happens when operations that occur close together in time will cause the problem but provided enough time in between operations the problem will not repro.Timing is everything with these issues

Comment: Also, to GhostCats point if your code is structured incorrectly, using Mockito will not be enough. Mockito is not capable of doing things such as mocking statics, as GhostCat has also mentioned. The same as I mentioned, your JUnit tests may not be doing what you think theyre doing if you dont understand the mocking framework correctly. Try to step through with a debugger and make sure the references to everything are mock references.This is a bit tricky though since both the debugger and Mocking frameworks modify the Java bytecode to do their separate tasks and the two won't play well together